# Изменение стиля к родительскому элементу JS

Tags: javascript, border, parent

Необходимо для дива completed сделать рамку красную. для expired синюю. Не могу обратиться к родительскому элементу.

```js
let a;
let b;
let dueStatus = document.querySelectorAll("div");
for(let q of dueStatus) {
    if (q.dataset.status == `completed`) {
        a = q.dataset.status;
        a.parentElement.style.border = "1px solid red";
        console.log(a);
    }
    else if (q.dataset.status == `expired`) {
        b = q.dataset.status;
        console.log(b);
    }
}
```

```html
  <div class="qqq" data-status="completed">
      Смотри фильм
  </div>

  <div class="qqq" data-status="expired">
      Читай книгу
  </div>
```

мое решение:

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь получить `parentElement` у строки.

```js
let a;
let b;
let dueStatus = document.querySelectorAll("div");
for(let q of dueStatus) {
    if (q.dataset.status == `completed`) {
        a = q.dataset.status;
        q.style.border = "1px solid red";
        console.log(a);
    }
    else if (q.dataset.status == `expired`) {
        b = q.dataset.status;
        q.style.border = "1px solid blue";
        console.log(b);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="qqq" data-status="completed">
      Смотри фильм
  </div>

  <div class="qqq" data-status="expired">
      Читай книгу
  </div>
```

Comment: а как по другому добраться?

Comment: `for(let q of dueStatus)` вы в `q` получаете этот самый "родительский" блок.

Comment: Большое спасибо. На пару часов на элементарной ошибке выпал:(

Comment: Если ответ был полезен - нажмите стрелочку вверх и если решает вашу проблему - галочку.

Answer (score 0):

Не забывайте также про возможности CSS:

```css
.qqq[data-status=completed] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.qqq[data-status=expired] {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="qqq" data-status="completed">
  Смотри фильм
</div>

<div class="qqq" data-status="expired">
  Читай книгу
</div>
```